# Why didn't the Bond of Blood charm break when Harry fled from the Dursleys after inflating aunt Marge?

Tags: harry-potter

In *Prisoner of Azkaban* Harry flees from the Dursleys after inflating his aunt. He quite literally LEAVES the house, apparently with no intent to come back but to live as an outcast in the Wizarding World.

Now the Bond of Blood charm which protects Harry breaks only under 2 conditions:

- He should become 17 years of age,
- He should leave the house and call it home no more.

In the situation I mentioned above, condition 2 has been breached. So why didn't the Bond of Blood charm break?

Comment: "*You need return there only once a year, but as long as you can still call it home, there he cannot hurt you.*

Comment: Harry did this before Dumbledore TOLD him. Before then Harry would have no reason to call it home .what's more,  read my first paragraph again. Harry was planning to leave the Dursleys

Comment: Because plot hole?

Comment: “*I thought*,” said Dumbledore, inclining his head slightly, “*that she
might need reminding of the pact she had sealed by taking you*" .......

It was his mother's blood that was the protection, calling the house as a protection was merely figurative.

Comment: And it didn't just rely on Harry *leaving* the house, it also counted on Petunia denouncing Harry. FYI, Harry also ran away from the house in Book 2. In the first book he also left the same way with Hagrid.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How long does a blood protection last for?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/235873/how-long-does-a-blood-protection-last-for)

Comment: @TimSparrow No it doesn't. I already read that question before I asked this. No answers there. The said answer itself says > " or when Harry leaves Privet Drive with no intention of coming back '

Comment: Moody put it better, I think: "You and your aunt and uncle are going your separate ways tonight, in the full understanding that you're never going to live together again, correct?  So this time, when you leave, there'll be no going back, and the charm will break the moment you get outside its range."

Comment: Harry's departure in book 3, by contrast, was basically just a teenage temper tantrum.  It wouldn't be much of a charm if that was enough to break it!

Comment: @Harry Johnston Moody's quote looks like a legit answer to this question. Maybe worth posting it as an answer?

Answer (score 7):

As soon as he reaches Diagon Alley he is greeted by Fudge who tells him that his Aunt as been deflated and her memory has been modified and also that his aunt and uncle have **agreed to take him back** next year. This is why the bond didn't break.

Here is the passage from PoA, chapter 3: The Knight Bus

> Fudge smiled at Harry over the rim of his teacup, rather like an uncle surveying a favorite nephew. Harry, who couldn’t believe his ears, opened his mouth to speak, couldn’t think of anything to say,and closed it again.
>
> “Ah, you’re worrying about the reaction of your aunt and uncle?” said Fudge.
>
> “Well, I won’t deny that they are extremely angry, Harry, **but they are prepared to take you back next summer as long as you stay at Hogwarts for the Christmas and Easter holidays.**”